# Python Decision Tree Image sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working with a baseball data set where each row is an individual pitch. Each column is an attribute about that pitch. Example 1 pitch could be 95 mph, 2,000 RPM spin rate, Exit velocity off the bat of 100mph, etc.

I built a decision tree off of the code from this webpage below, and used pitch velocity, and spin rate to predict whether that pitch resulted in a hit or not. I got 81% accuracy... but who cares? I need to be able to have some insight from the decision tree. For example I need to be able to read something like, Pitches over 95mph with spin rates over 3,000 result in "not a hit" 87% of the time.

How do I plot the image of my decision tree to see this kind of data that I can make recommendations on?

http://dataaspirant.com/2017/02/01/decision-tree-algorithm-python-with-scikit-learn/

Comment: See https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193424/is-decision-tree-output-a-prediction-or-class-probabilities&ved=2ahUKEwjl5NbKk47aAhUNnRQKHZaKBmUQjjgwJHoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw20U2ztqV0btmoFpSxYubS8

Answer (score 0):

Dump decision tree model after training to a file using code

```
with open("fine_name.dot", 'w') as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(tree_name, out_file=f, feature_names=columns)
```

Copy content of file generated and paste in editor of http://webgraphviz.com/ to visualize decision tree. It converts Decision tree to a white box :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use tree.plot_tree to get an image of tree.